# Byte Buffer to BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, image, stream, byte, buffer

I am receiving data from a server via a socket. This data is being written into a buffer, and the contents are inspected for some condition (at which point we stop receiving data).

The data being sent relates to an image. Hence, I need to turn this into an input stream that I can then pass to ImageIO.read to get a buffered image. How do I create such an input stream (where the bytes are distributed over time across an constantly updated buffer)?

Is it possible to do the following, and if so how?

buffer ---(piped to)----> bufferedInputStream ?

Comment: Do you suggest that I just send to a temporary file, and then reconstruct bufferedImage from that file?

Comment: PipedInputStream + PipedOutputStream?

Comment: *This data is being read into a buffer* - not sure what that means, but maybe you can use a ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: @camickr apologies. *Written* into a buffer.

Comment: Which buffer are you using, `ByteBuffer`?

Comment: I meant I don't know what "buffer" is.  "buffer" is not a class. I don't know how the data is being stored. If it is a ByteBuffer as suggested by Aman, then maybe you can get the array from the ByteBuffer and use the ByteArrayInputStream as the input to the ImageIO.read(...) metthod.

Comment: @camickr By buffer I meant a byte[]. I thought buffer was a synonym for a byte array but I presume not.

Comment: A buffer just holds something. If you look at the API you will find a "Buffer" class. It has sub classes for all the primitive data types. In your case you decided to create your own byte array (which is relevant information for the question). It could have been a char array. You might be able to use the `ByteBuffer` class so you don't reinvent the wheel. In any case I provided a suggestion. Did it work?

Comment: I believe there exists (in JAI?) `ImageInputStream` implementations that can be backed by a `ByteBuffer`, without intermediate storage. If not, it should be possible to write one. But if you have a limited buffer that gets overwritten, you may need the intermediate storage anyway, so just using a temp file or `ByteArrayInput/OutputStream` may make sense.